# In Symfony2 using the AsseticBundle tool, based on the .Less file to create all the .Css files to web directory, the program into an infinite loop？

Tags: symfony, less, assetic

I can't find the reason. Please help me.

I use this command generate .css file to web directory:

```
$sudo php app/console assetic:dump
```

Error information:

```
 [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\OutOfMemoryException]                                       
 Error: Allowed memory size of 5368709120 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4205621120 bytes)
```

$ls /opt/webroot/symfony/web/css
[image: file list]

```
 //views/base.html.twig

    {% block head_style %}
    {% stylesheets filter='less,cssrewrite'
    '@ScourgenPersonFinderBundle/Resources/public/less/style.less'
    '@BloggerBlogBundle/Resources/css/style.css'
    %}
    <link href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>
    {% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock head_style %}


   #app/config/config.yml
    assetic:
      debug:          '%kernel.debug%'
 #    use_controller: '%kernel.debug%'
use_controller: false
bundles:
    - ScourgenPersonFinderBundle
    - MopaBootstrapBundle
    - BloggerBlogBundle
filters:
    cssrewrite: ~
     #        yui_css:
   #            jar: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yuicompressor/build/yuicompressor-2.4.8.jarw
    less:
        node: /usr/local/bin/node
        node_paths: [/usr/local/lib/node_modules, /opt/lessc]
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? I think we have the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47812311/large-image-folder-crashes-symfony-cacheclear-with-outofmemoryexception/47812348